# what is difference between register_name and register functions in Erlang

Tags: erlang

What is difference between register_name and register functions in Erlang?
Both register a PID as a name!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digging up the documentation, I discovered that `register()` is part of the `erlang` module while `register_name()` is part of the `global` module. So, it appears the main difference between the two functions is that `register_name()` will register a name globally for a network of Erlang nodes.

> **The ability to globally register names is a central concept in the
>   programming of distributed Erlang systems. In this module, the
>   equivalent of the register/2 and whereis/1 BIFs (for local name
>   registration) are implemented, but for a network of Erlang nodes.** A
>   registered name is an alias for a process identifier (pid). The global
>   name server monitors globally registered pids. If a process
>   terminates, the name will also be globally unregistered.

[Source](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/global.html)

Answer (score 2):

register_name is part of the Global module and deals with registering Pids globally, across a system of many nodes.  register/2 is part of the Erlang module and associates a name with a Pid for the local node.